# What is the maximum range over open water with twin-engine to require dinghy in EASA?

Tags: easa-regulations, equipment, ditching

What is the maximum range for a twin-engine aircraft to fly over open water before having the requirement for flotation devices (vests / dinghy) under EASA-rules?

Answer (score 1):

### For landplanes

#### No flotation devices:

- Remain within 50 NM from **"shore".**
- Unless, takeoff/landing path is over water with a ditching likelihood.

#### Life-jackets:

- If takeoff/landing path is over water with a ditching likelihood.
- Greater than 50 NM from "land suitable for making an emergency landing".

#### Life-jackets *and* life rafts:

- Greater than 100 NM / 30 minutes at cruising speed (whichever is the lesser) from **"land suitable for making an emergency landing".**
- Or, for airplanes that are capable of sustaining flight to an **"aerodrome"** after a [critical engine](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Critical_Engine)(s) becoming inoperative, then when greater than 400 NM / 120 min at cruising speed (whichever is the lesser) from said aerodrome(s).

---

Reference and more on equipment: [Commission Regulation (EU) No 965/2012](https://www.easa.europa.eu/document-library/regulations/commission-regulation-eu-no-9652012) § CAT.IDE.A.285 Flight over water